# rbenv install not downloading ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, openssl, rbenv

Installing ruby version with rbenv `rbenv install -l`returns the proper list. However

```
$ rbenv install 2.3.4 -v
```

fails on the download, even though it can be downloaded via a browser.  My hunch about an improper version of openssl (due to some distant memory of having such issues - tls version? - in the past) is supported in verbose mode:

```
ruby-build: use openssl from homebrew 
/var/folders/kV/kVDOSPkcEuqSVnTjenAVRE+++TI/-Tmp-/ruby-build.20170601122915.1010 ~ Downloading ruby-2.3.4.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.4.tar.bz2 
curl: (35)    error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version 
error: failed to download ruby-2.3.4.tar.bz2
```

how to overcome?  can I point rbenv to use the downloaded tarball?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is because rbenv use old system **curl** and old system **openssl** with it, which knows nothing about protocols TLS v 1.1-1.3. For me, installing new version of **curl** and **openssl** with brew did the work:

```
brew install openssl@1.1
brew install curl
```

Then add installed curl to your PATH (before default path, which is /usr/bin), and ensure that openssl of actual brew's version is also there (add this to your ./bash_profile or ./zshrc or etc):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"
```

You can make sure after relaunch of terminal that latest versions of this programs will be used by trying

```
which -a openssl
which -a curl
openssl version -a
curl -V
```

First two commands should output all paths with the programs, but top ones should be brew versions. Last two commands should show latest versions of programs (1.1.0f and 7.55 for me now).
Now try

```
rbenv install [version]
```

Works on MacOS Sierra with enabled SIP.

Comment: Great answer, however, on El Cap - still wouldn't use the new curl version. Had to go to usr/bin and just delete curl.

Comment: @TimJoyce, hm, i can not imagine something, that could be reason for that. Also for the reason why you still using El Cap :)